# PHP regex match numbers from string before specified character

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I have string that its output result could be like:

```
First : 14:15
Second: 14:2
Third: 10:2
Fourht: 1:20
Fifth: 1:5
```

I have regex that matches only first and third example from above:

```
/(^[0-9]{2})/
```

If there is output like 1:10 or 1:2 there is no output (error).

Wanted result:

```
14
14
10 
1
1
```

Can I do it with preg_replace() or some other? Do I need to change my regex too? If so, which regex should I use to match numbers before ":" character?

Thanks for info and help!

Comment: why not just explode on `:` and pick out the 2nd element from the resulting array? `explode(':', 'First : 14 : 15')[1]`?

Comment: Wait, does your input look like `14:15`, etc.? Then just `explode`, really. If the strings are known to only include digits separated with a `:`, it is the only best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To re-state, regex is *not* the correct tool for this job.

```
$output = explode(":",$input)[0];
```

Comment: Got it working with Your answer :)

Comment: But I believe regex could be fine too https://3v4l.org/bkRj3

Comment: Also your approach doesn't work https://3v4l.org/Qm3ft

Comment: @Shafizadeh It does work if you have the right input - the question is extremely badly worded but the input is more like `$first = "14:15";`

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!

```
preg_match_all('(^(.*):)', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0]; // output is right! 14, 14, 10, 1, 1
```

https://regex101.com/r/aZ5uQ6/1

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: If your string contains more than 1 `:`, this won't work.

Comment: Regex is NOT the correct tool for this job.

Comment: Hm... I will keep this on my mind! Currently it does not contains more than one. Thanks!

Comment: The input you've shown in this example is not what you've written in the question.